# Ignore type checking of node modules files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, node-modules, tsconfig

Is there any way to ignore the node modules files while running the `npm run check-types` command?

I already tried adding the flag `skipLibCheck`, but it only ignores `.d.ts` files. The package I'm using consists of `.ts` files as well. I also tried some other ways like including `maxNodeModuleJsDepth` and set its value to 0, but that also didn't work.

Comment: What is your `check-types` script?